# Postgres getting duplicate key exception (DELETE AND INSERT) from inside psql function

Tags: postgresql, multithreading, optimization

I am trying to update the table with huge data. On checking I figured that upsert (Update and insert) is slow compared to using the temp table to delete and then insert from temp table. But I am facing issue with duplicate data in such scenario.
As far as I understand the delete and insert is happening in same transaction, so I could not understand why I am facing duplicate data issue when I have already deleted the data with the delete.
This is multithreaded scenario but i guess the other transaction will have its own set of data.
Any help is appreciated here.
Sample code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertUsingTempTable(a_id int, s_obj int[], p bigint[])
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $BODY$
DECLARE passed BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
        CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_lists AS SELECT * FROM acm_lists WHERE 0=1;
        TRUNCATE TABLE temp_lists;
        INSERT INTO temp_lists(a_id, s_obj_id, eff_p)
         SELECT a_id , unnest($2::int[]), unnest($3::bit(64)[]) ;
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT t.a_id, s_obj_id, count(1) FROM temp_lists t
         GROUP BY t.a_id, s_obj_id HAVING count(1) > 1) THEN
            DELETE FROM acm_lists t WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_lists t1
              WHERE t1.a_id=t.a_id AND s_obj_id=t.s_obj_id);
            INSERT INTO acm_lists (a_id, s_obj_id, eff_p) 
                SELECT t.a_id, t.s_obj_id,  t.eff_p FROM temp_lists t;
            RETURN true;
        END IF;
        RETURN false;
END;
$BODY$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Uniqueness is on a_id, s_obj_id in the above code.

I would like to know why duplicate exception is coming at times, if I am already deleting the data before inserting. This happens only when multiple transactions are running at the same time on the table.
`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` resolves the issue, but seems there is considerable performance hit. so I don't plan to use ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE approach.

Comment: If you want to update existing rows in the acm_lists table, why don't you simply use the `UPDATE acm_lists SET ...` action in postgres ? Or if you don't know when some rows should be updated and some others should be inserted, then you can use `INSERT INTO acm_lists ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET ... WHERE ...` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Comment: As already mentioned UPDATE with insert is slow.  My point is why am I getting duplicate exception when I have already deleted the data. INSERT ... on CONFLICT .. is something that can be done, but even that will cause update on a very large table causing slowness. Point being, If I have already deleted  such a data, I shouldn't get the exception.

Comment: Check your *Input* data for duplicates. I.E. duplicates in a_id int, s_obj int[], p bigint[] against  unique constraints/indexes on your output table.

Comment: @Belayer I am already checking in NOT EXISTS in the above function before inserting, INSERT INTO acm_lists (a_id, s_obj_id, eff_p) SELECT t.a_id, t.s_obj_id, t.eff_p FROM temp_lists t; is giving duplicate exception